# First-timer questions for developing language families, been trying out Vulgarlang

Tags: conlang-creation

I'm currently working on a project of mine, an overhaul modification for the game Victoria 3 and I'm digging deeper into the phase for making unique languages to represent portions of every continent/world.

I began for the longest just re-hashing what we have in real life, either using branches of a family or combining say, Pashtun and Japanese to create like "Nipponistan" for example. I don't have an issue with it, but when I got stuck coming up with more unique combinations or uncommon languages I stumbled upon conlang communities and Vulgerlang. Which seems to be controversial too.

I'm not that close to being a perfectionist so while I would love to uniquely customize my entire language in Vulgerlang, phonology, grammar, feels overwhelming. So I guess I've been more focused on just constructing an eligible language for appearance moreso, with the concepts I understand comprehensively, and appears to mirror what is in real life I desire.

---So, if I want to create a language family that appears English-esque, that spawned off an old empires language that is Tamil/Arabic, is it better if I start off basing my phonemes and the regular stuff off Arabic, or English?

---Do I lean towards removing the Semitic triconsonant in the new family, or do I remove more what defines an English/Germanic language and include some minor, moderate Semitic features?

---For my project, what would best visually communicate the differences between languages in a family group? I read that its mostly sound-based from our mouths with little other bits here and there mutated away from each other.

---I know its subjective, but how would you recognize a conlang that is good? That seems pretty realistic and capable of portraying many ideas and words?

Thanks for helping me out. I really enjoy this process, but I'm afraid of the amount of time I'm using of mine wandering aimlessly into it.

Comment: Welcome here, NagaPrince! You have quite a catalog of questions here, and it is better to ask every question separately. I suggest that you take the [tour](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/tour) to this site and visit the [help centre](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/help) for more detailed advice on how to aks good questions.